Element in REAL(4) array constructor at (1) is REAL(8)
I'm trying to run a simple Fortran code:
program training
implicit none

real*8, dimension(2) :: theta_angle
real*8, parameter :: pi = 3.14159
theta_angle = (/0.0, pi/2/)

end program training

But I got the error:
F:\LATS\material test\training.f90:7:24:
7 |     theta_angle = (/0.0, pi/2/)
  |                        1

Error: Element in REAL(4) array constructor at (1) is REAL(8)
I spent a lot of time trying to solve it but couldn't. Please explain to me the reason

Please post the code and error message.  Do not post a screenshot.  We cannot run a screenshot through our tools.

0.0 is not double precision.

How should I fix it (I'm a Fortran newbie)

Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've got links to previous posts on this site that contain solutions to problems that seem to be the same as the one you are facing. In your case probably replacing theta_angle = (/0.0, pi/2/) with theta_angle = (/0.0d0, pi/2/) would suffice.

Thank for your replies! I have solved my problem. I have read previous posts but it's quite difficult for me.
